# How do I change the URL in Django framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to make a website using Django and I got some error message like this

```
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/store.html

Using the URLconf defined in greatkart.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/
    [name='home']
    store/
    ^media/(?P<path>.*)$

The current path, store.html, didn't match any of these.
```

The problem is when I tried to click button it always print ./store.html not the ./store
it's my html code for the button

```
<a href="./store.html" class="btn btn-outline-primary float-right">See all</a>
```

And this is my Django for urls.py (main)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('store/', include("store.urls"))
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This urls.py(store)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.store, name='store'),
    path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.store, name='product_by_category'),
]
```

views.py

```
def store(request, category_slug = None):
    return render(request, 'store/store.html', context)
```

Anyone have some idea? I want to fix it without changing the HTML code because I've tried it and when I click on the buttons twice that make some error because the URL print the ./store twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the url should be absolute(starting with a `/` excluding you localhost address) and should not include `.html`.
So Your Url should be :
`/store`
and the anchor tag should be :
`<a href="/store" class="btn btn-outline-primary float-right">See all</a>`

Comment: oh i see the problem i'm include ./store and not /store so it's print /store whenever i clcik the button thank you for your help

Comment: @MarcusAurelius , I'm glad it helped. Consider upvoting the answer and accept it as a solution. Please :)